# While loop in parent function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble interpreting what this code is doing.  Here it is:

```
function parent(e, n) { 

    if (n === undefined) n = 1; //if n is not defined, use 1 by default

    while(n-- && e) e = e.parentNode; 

    if (!e || e.nodeType !== 1) return null; 

    return e;   

}
```

This function accepts two arguments.  One for the element and the second for the ancestor of the element.  So, passing a 2 in the second argument would retrieve the grandparent of the element (2 elements up the DOM tree).

I understand all of it, except for the `while` loop.  I am not sure how counting backwards is selecting that specific ancestor.  How does this while loop work making this function select an ancestor??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important point here is that numbers are "truthy" (or falsy).  `0` acts the same as `false`.  Therefore, when `n` reaches zero the loop ends.

So, if `n` starts at 2, the loop will run, at most, 2 times.

The other condition is slightly more understandable.  If the node has no parent then the loop will also terminate.

Each iteration of the loop does `e = e.parentNode`, which gets the parent of the "current" node.  If the loop executes 2 iterations, that will move 2 layers up the dom (the "grandparent").

Comment: I get that the while loop will terminate if it reaches zero..  But how exactly does the function know to go up two DOM elements??  I don't see that logic anywhere.

Comment: `e = e.parentNode` "goes up" one level.  This is in a loop that executes `n` times.

Comment: Ah!  That just clicked with me.  Add that to the answer and I will give you the check mark.  That just made it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it gets the nth parent element...

Comment: Too true, I definitely should have read more carefully, sorry about that!  Should I delete my response?  What's the proper etiquette?

Comment: I can see you'll be a quick learner :) By all means, any time you can expand upon or improve your answer, do it. In this case, since the question is already marked as answered by someone else, it probably won't have much effect (unless your answer ends up even better).

Comment: Good to know, thanks so much ewall for learning me to be a better stackoverflow-er!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the loop looks at the parentNode of the passed in element.  So, if you pass in a specific div with 1 as the iterating factor, it will look at the immediate parent of the div.  If you pass in 2, it will look 2 parents up (the parent of the parent of the div).  It does this by using e.parentNode and resetting e to its parent with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var n = 2;
while(n--) console.log("do this " + n + " more times.");

if(0){
  console.log("never executed because zero is evaluated as false");
}
```

In a browser that supports console.log.

Answer has been given before stating that the number 0 is evaluated as false.

n-- means return the value of n and then subtract one. If you would have --n in the above code than it would do it only one time (subtract first).

In your code if n would be 2 the loop would execute 2 times, in the loop variable e (the element) is set to the element's parent node. If there is no parent node than e would be undefined in that case the statement if(e){...} would not do anything because evaluating an undefined value results in false. So n && e would return false even if n is not 0 when e is undefined (like not having a parent node).